# How to make nested layouts with jquery-layout resizable?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-layout

I'm trying to create a 4-pane layout using the [jQuery-Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/) plugin.

Really basic stuff:

The layout (note that I use `iframe`s):

```
<iframe class="ui-layout-center">Outer Center</iframe>
<iframe class="ui-layout-east">Outer East</iframe>
<div class="ui-layout-west ">
    <iframe class="ui-layout-south">Middle South</iframe>
    <div class="ui-layout-center ">
        <iframe class="ui-layout-center">Inner Center</iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').layout({
        west__childOptions: {
            center__childOptions: {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wpbwqevo/2/)

[Updated, simpler fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wpbwqevo/3/)

All is well until I try to resize the panes. It *kinda* works, but is very rough. When dragging the pane resizer handles it looks like they lose contact with the mouse pointer and stop resizing.

If the panes are simple `divs`, everything works, but not if the panes are `iframes` (which is what I need).

Any idea on how I could debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jquery-ui-layout/resize$20iframe/jquery-ui-layout/syYUbUn3X3c/QpH933k8b6YJ)

Basically, you need to mask each panel (and its parents, in case of nested panels) that contains an `iframe`.

Like this:

```
$('body').layout({
        center__maskContents:  true,
        west__maskContents:  true
});
```

Here's the working demo of the fiddle from the question: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/wpbwqevo/4/)